# Deploying React App with Spring Boot REST API in AWS BeanStalk

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy 2 instances (front and back end) separately. Currently, the back end which is the REST API using SpringBoot was successfully deployed in BeanStalk as a .jar file. Now, I have never deploy a front end app (in my case my React app) separately in AWS BeanStalk and I have been doing my research but I'm stuck. How do I "compile" my React app and deploy it in BeanStalk like I did with the back end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, for anyone in the future needs help with this, all you have to do just follow these steps:

1. Create a bucket and allow complete public access
2. Go to permission -> bucket policy -> add this script

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::(name-of-your-bucket)/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

3. add this to your package.json under scripts

`"deploy": "aws s3 cp --recursive ./build s3://(your-bucket-name)",`

4. execute **npm run build** in terminal
5. execute `aws s3 cp --recursive ./build s3://(your-bucket-name) in terminal` (you are uploading your build files inside the build folder to s3)
6. go to properties -> static web hosting -> point out the index.html if you use that -> click the end point

Comment: How do you get access from your S3 to your beanstalk?

Comment: @AhmedAziz you need to enable the IAM policy of the S3 for the beanstalk to grab stuff from the S3 bucket